# In text Citation

Tags: punctuation, citation

If your quote is at the end of a sentence and is the end of its own sentence as well does the period go inside the parentheses or outside of it? Also what would you do with the in text citation (page number)?

Answer (score 1):

Patrick Henry said, "Give me liberty or give me death" (Smith and Wesson, *Great American Quotations*, p.73).

If the quotation is not quoted in its entirety, you can put an ellipsis (with a space between each period in the ellipsis) at the end of it, and put the final period after the citation, if there is one.

> Patrick Henry said, "Give me liberty . . ." (Smith and Wesson, *Great American Quotations*, p.73).

By the way, if you have further questions, just Google "quotations and punctuation."  I'll bet you get a bazillion sources of relevant information from which to pick.